# Get input fields with a value inside a div using .closest

Tags: jquery

I'm using JQuery to get the closest div with a specific class and creating a variable:

```
var box = $(this).closest('.box');
```

How can i then get all inputs with a class of `required` inside this variable div?

I've tried this:

```
    var errors = false;
    $(box + " input .required").each(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
        if($(this).val() === "") {
            errors = true;

            $(this).parent().find('label').css("color", "#f36f25");
            $(this).parent().find('label').css("font-weight", "bold");
        }
    });
```

but get an error in the console saying `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] input .required`

Comment: `box.find(‘input.required’);`?

Comment: will that allow me to do an .each loop over all inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the code

```
var box = $(this).closest('.box');
```

and

```
$(box + " input .required").each(function() {
```

then that means the line `$(box + " input .required").each(function() {` actually reads like

```
$($(this).closest('.box')+ " input .required").each(function() {
```

which is syntactically invalid. You are trying to append a jquery selection object with a string, all within another jquery selector. That just doesn't work.

You want to do `box.find("input.required").each(....`

Resulting code looks like this:

```
var box = $(this).closest('.box');

var errors = false;
box.find("input.required").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
    if($(this).val() === "") {
        errors = true;

        $(this).parent().find('label').css("color", "#f36f25");
        $(this).parent().find('label').css("font-weight", "bold");
    }
});
```